# ssh key with image fingerprint

Tags: ssh, image, hash

SSH key fingerprint is shown by running this command:

```
ssh-keygen -lf /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
```

and the fingerprint is some strange code. Is there a way to turn this code into an image hash or something like Gravatar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a `-v` for ASCII art:

```
michael@challenger:~> ssh-keygen -lf /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub -v
1024 8a:84:4e:34:60:9c:64:94:d0:29:0b:75:82:60:2c:89 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub (RSA)
+--[ RSA 1024]----+
|%@=..            |
|E*oo             |
|ooo              |
|.. o             |
|  o .   S        |
| o . . .         |
|  . . .          |
|                 |
|                 |
+-----------------+
```

If you want an image, I don't suppose you've tried Just Doing It with Gravatar:

https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8a844e34609c6494d0290b7582602c89?d=identicon&r=PG

[image: challenger's SSH key gravatar]

Ooohhh... I like it! Triforce action!